# How do I let users choose a calendar from their device

Tags: android, android-calendar

My app adds events to a user's calendar. However I am currently using the first valid calendar (usually id 1). What would be the best method for the user to select from the available calendars on their device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got it by myself
In the layout I have a spinner and it is populated and maintained by this method that is ran on resume

```
    public void getCalendarsForCheckBox(){


    String[] projection =
            new String[]{
                    Calendars._ID,
                    Calendars.NAME,
                    Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME,
                    Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE};

    Uri calendars = Uri.parse("content://calendar/calendars");
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor managedCursor =
            getContentResolver().
                    query(Calendars.CONTENT_URI,
                            projection,
                            Calendars.VISIBLE + " = 1",
                            null,
                            Calendars._ID + " ASC");
    int j=0;
    if (managedCursor.moveToFirst()) {

        String calName;
        Integer calId;
        int nameColumn = managedCursor.getColumnIndex("name");

        int idColumn = managedCursor.getColumnIndex("_id");
        Integer i=0;
        do {

            calName = managedCursor.getString(nameColumn);

            if (!(calName == null)) {

                j++;
            }

        } while (managedCursor.moveToNext());

    }
//retrieving previously selected calendar (defaults to id 1)
    SharedPreferences prefs = getBaseContext().getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    Integer theID = prefs.getInt("calendarID",1);
    Integer indexToSelect=0;
    String calTitles[] = new String[j];
    if (managedCursor.moveToFirst()) {

        String calName;
        Integer calId;
        int nameColumn = managedCursor.getColumnIndex("name");

        int idColumn = managedCursor.getColumnIndex("_id");
        Integer i=0;
        do {

            calName = managedCursor.getString(nameColumn);
            calId = Integer.parseInt(managedCursor.getString(idColumn));
            if (!(calName == null)) {
                if (calId.equals(theID))  indexToSelect = i;
                calTitles[i] = calName + "-" + calId;
                i++;
            }

        } while (managedCursor.moveToNext());

    }
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, calTitles); //selected item will look like a spinner set from XML


    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setSelection(indexToSelect);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
            String findTheIdSplit[] = ((TextView)selectedItemView).getText().toString().split("-");
            Integer TheID = Integer.parseInt(findTheIdSplit[findTheIdSplit.length-1]);

            SharedPreferences prefs = getBaseContext().getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putInt("calendarID",TheID);
            editor.commit();
//for committing the selected calendar

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
            // your code here if needed
        }

    });

}
```